# Unable to load classpath; Failed to dispatch (def payload = new com.eviware.soapui.support. XmlHolder(mockRequest.requestContent)

Tags: soap, groovy, soapui

I'm using the following code exactly from the book 'Web Services testing with SoapUI' to dynamically mock a service for a hotel. The service has classes for guest management, room management and making reservations. I'm trying to add the folowing code from the book

```
def payload = new com.eviware.soapui.support. XmlHolder(mockRequest.requestContent) def guestname = payload["//typ:getGuestDetails/typ:guestName"] def response = "";
....
```

This gives the error

```
com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.mock.DispatchException: Failed to dispatch using script; 
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script11.groovy: 1: unable to resolve class com.eviware.soapui.support.XMLHolder @ line 1,
column 1. import com.eviware.soapui.support.XMLHolder ^org.codehaus.groovy.syntax.SyntaxException: unable to resolve class
com.eviware.soapui.support.XMLHolder @ line 1, column 1. at
org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.addError(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:146) at
org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.visitClass(ResolveVisitor.java:1145) at
org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.startResolving(ResolveVisitor.java:141) at
org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$10.call(CompilationUnit.java:632) at
org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:912) at
org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:574) at
org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:523) at
groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:279) at
groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:258) at
groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:613) at
groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:625) at
groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:652) at
groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:643) at
com.eviware.soapui.support.scripting.groovy.SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.compile(SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.java:152) at
com.eviware.soapui.support.scripting.groovy.SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.run(SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.java:97) at
com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.mock.dispatch.ScriptMockOperationDispatcher.selectMockResponse(ScriptMockOperationDispatcher.java:81) at
com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.mock.dispatch.ScriptMockOperationDispatcher$RunScriptAction.actionPerformed(ScriptMockOperationDispatcher.java:237) at
javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source) at
javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source) at
javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source) at 
javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source) at
javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source) at
java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(Unknown Source) at
java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source) at
javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source) at
java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source) at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source) at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) at
java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) at
java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) at
java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source) at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source) at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) at
java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(UnknownSource) at
java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) at
java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source) at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source) at
java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source) at
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at
java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source) at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source) at 
java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source) at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source) at 
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at
java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source) at
java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) at
java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source) at
java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source) at
java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source) at
java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source) at
java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source) at
java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source) 1 error
```

How can I resolve this error.

Answer (score 0):

At first I guess that it's a classpath problem, but it isn't probably the reason because the exception that your script it's thrown is `com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.mock.DispatchException` which is in the same jar that `com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder`. So then I realize there is a thing that I don't understand in your question, in java (and groovy) the class names are case sensitive so if you want to use `com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder`class you can't use `com.eviware.soapui.support.XMLHolder`. In your code sample which you post I see that you're using the correct syntax:

`def payload = new com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder`

But in your stacktrace I see that you're using the wrong class name on the `import`:

`... unable to resolve class com.eviware.soapui.support.XMLHolder @ line 1,
column 1. import com.eviware.soapui.support.XMLHolder...`

So the error is in the `import` statment, use:

`import com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder`

instead of

`import com.eviware.soapui.support.XMLHolder`

Hope this helps,